# Create Raster boundary polygon in Metashape itself using DEM or OrthoMosaic generated in Agisoft Metashape

Tags: agisoft-photoscan

Is there any script/code/help available to create raster boundary polygon using OrthoMosaic created after DEM in Metashape. Sometimes it is required to calculate survey area covered/Processed

[image]

Comment: Metashape Professional has an area calculation under `Tools > Mesh`. Maybe photoscan has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...
[This Python tool](https://github.com/LummiGIS/Drone_Image_Overlap_Counter) is part of a two part script process to produce a raster layer where the resulting raster values are the image overlap count for that portion of your reconstruction.

[This first script](https://github.com/LummiGIS/Drone_Image_Overlap_Counter/blob/main/GetImageFootprints.py) (taken from the Agisoft website) produces an ESRI shapefile for each image footprint in the reconstruction.  This script needs to be executed in a Python window inside of Agisoft.

[This second script](https://github.com/LummiGIS/Drone_Image_Overlap_Counter/blob/main/CreateImageOverlapCountRasterFromAgisoftFootprintFile.py) executed in your favorite Python IDE will produce the raster layer from that resulting shapefile.  The second script requires an arcpy installation with a Spatial Analyst license. There is a script for arcpy 10.8 and arcpy 2.9.

Because Agisoft will reconstruct with only a few overlapping images, the resulting raster can be reclassified and used to remove poor quality pixels on the outer edge of the reconstruction based an overlap count of your choosing.

The Agisoft shapefile tool has been tested in both Agisoft Photoscan and Agisoft Metashape.  I am the author of the second script so send me any error messages you encounter and I will attempt to address the problem.